# Querying MySql zero dates with NHibernate

Tags: mysql, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm contacting a legacy database using NHibernate, but I'm having problems with MySql's zero dates.

The column is defined as `DATETIME NULL`, but it's storing "null" values as a blank date.
I've added `Convert Zero Datetime=true` to my connectionstring, so now all values are converted to `DateTime.MinValue`. On the other hand. It doesn't seem NHibernate understands this, and doesn't convert `DateTime.MinValue` to a blank MySql datetime when querying.

```
// So this query always returns a blank result.
Where(x => x.SomeDateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
// And so does this
Where(x => x.SomeDateTime == null)
```

I thought about using `MySqlDateTime` directly for these fields, but that is just plain ugly, and I need to implement arithmetic on it myself..

Any idea how I can handle this elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing with NULL is not the same as using the `IS NULL` test.  The database doesn't actually put a null value in there, it sets a flag in another (hidden) field.

```
Where(x => x.SomeDateTime is null)
```

Comment: Your misunderstanding. There are no null values in the database, it's MySql's empty datetimes; "0000-00-00 00:00:00". These are the problem.

Comment: How was the data written?  If there was no datetime available for a record, was the date 0001-01-01 written?  I'm pretty sure 0000-00-00 is transformed into a NULL.

Comment: In MySql the zero date value is used for "illegal" dates. It doesn't have anything to do with null values. The .Net connector can fetch these illegal dates as DateTime.MinValue as the zero date cannot be converted to DateTime. The problem is when using this for querying with NHibernate. NHibernate doesn't seem to understand these illegal dates.